# How to use silex with Doctrine orm EntityManager?

Tags: doctrine-orm, entitymanager, silex

Am new to the Silex framework. And I would like to do simple SQL DB connection using doctrine entity manager. Kindly give some simple examples.

Thanks in Advance,
SK

Answer (score 17):

Here is a [working example](https://github.com/ooXei1sh/silex-ske-sandbox/tree/v0.1.4) of all the following setup below. There is also a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/ZscvXn0y9-0) explaining that setup. Or if you just want something that works right now try: [this](https://github.com/ooXei1sh/silex-ske-sandbox.git).

Otherwise the following is an attempt to explain one way to setup and **"use silex with Doctrine orm EntityManager"**:

### Install

Add this line into composer.json:

```
"dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider": "1.0.6"
```

From command line run:

```
~$ composer update dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider
```

### Register

Register the service provider:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Dflydev\Silex\Provider\DoctrineOrm\DoctrineOrmServiceProvider());
```

### Configure

Configure your database and entity mappings. **Your paths may be different**. A better and more detailed explaination can be found in the [Doctrine ORM Service Provider README](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider/blob/v1.0.6/README.md#silex):

```
$app['db.options'] = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'dbname'   => '',
    'user'     => '',
    'password' => '',
);

$app['orm.proxies_dir'] = __DIR__.'/../cache/doctrine/proxies';
$app['orm.default_cache'] = 'array';
$app['orm.em.options'] = array(
    'mappings' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'annotation',
            'path' => __DIR__.'/../../src',
            'namespace' => 'My\\Namespace\\To\\Entity',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Likely you will want to setup `cli-config.php` for more info read the [Doctrine Configuration Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html):

```
<?php
    // http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html
    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    require __DIR__.'/path/to/app/config.php';
    $newDefaultAnnotationDrivers = array(
        __DIR__."/src/MyNamespace",
    );
    $config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache);
    $driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($newDefaultAnnotationDrivers);
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
    $config->setProxyDir($app['orm.proxies_dir']);
    $config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');
    $em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($app['db.options'], $config);
    $helpers = new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
        'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
        'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em),
    ));
```

### Take it for a spin

At this point you should be able to dump some schema from the command line assuming you have [annotated](http://doctrine-common.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations.html) [entities](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html) in `$newDefaultAnnotationDrivers` path:

```
~$ php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql
```

With the above setup in place you should also be able to use `$app['orm.em']` from a controller method:

```
$app->match('/form', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

    $em = $app['orm.em'];

    $entity = new \My\Namespace\To\Entity\Form();

    $form = $app['form.factory']->create(new \My\Namespace\To\Form\FormType(), $entity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return new Response($app['twig']->render('form.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    )));

})->bind('form');
```

Comment: cli-config.php is the tricky part, your answer helped a lot, thank you.

Comment: Note that `$config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver($newDefaultAnnotationDrivers);` also takes a second boolean argument (use simple annotations?). It may cause you a `No Metada Classes to process.` headache.

Comment: "dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider": "^2.0" - i'ts work version for me.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't an official Doctrine ORM service provider for Silex only the DBAL, but there are several [third party service providers](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/wiki/Third-Party-ServiceProviders) you can try.
I stared using [dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider) which has the most starts in github and looks nice.